# GCE Firewall rule based on service account doesn't really work

Tags: firewall, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have two projects on my own (P1 and P2) in Google Compute Engine and two service accounts (SA1 in P1 and SA2 in P2).
What I'm trying to achieve is that instances in P1 with SA1 can access to any resources in P2 which has SA2 let say to port 2345. I ensured that application is running and listening to 2345

What was done so far following [this](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) documentation https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls
I've created a new rule in P2 where the source is an SA1 and target is an SA2 but, it doesn't work and the port 2345 still unreachable.
Then I thought I need to specify the second source filter as 0.0.0.0/0 in considering that all resources work under SA1 no matter which IP it's coming from should work but, now it seems to be open to the world, what I'm trying to prevent of course.

I've spent a lot of time looking for the solution on the internet, without success. That seems like nobody had the similar issue before me 'cause I didn't find any record related to my problem.
Does anybody knows what I'm doing wrong or missing something

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi,

Can you first try to connect from one VM to another in the same project following this link (https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#serviceaccounts) document?

Comment: Sorry **Digil**, missed your message and thanks for your inputs. Yes, I am able to connect with no problems following the above documentation. The issue starts only when I'm trying to do the same for different projects.

Comment: I know this is an old topic. But I am running into the same issue and I _think_ it is because the feature only works for local networks, not externally routed IP addresses. It makes sense that there wouldn't be a way to determine the source service account for an externally routed source. At that point in the routing process, it probably works just like any other incoming external IP address. The only data you have as a filter would be port, IP, and protocol.

Comment: I have the same problem. Neither --source-service-accounts not --source-tags work for source instances inside different project. Only --source-ranges seems to work.